# Socket.io auto disconnect in android when user blur the app

Tags: android, websocket, socket.io

I have a application built in React Native (Mobile) and Node js (Backend). When user is in my app and goes to another app and stays in this app for few minutes, my socket is automatically disconnected.

I saw some 'fix' increasing pingTimeout and pingInterval, is it a solution or is there another solution?

Fix this, and not disconnect user

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.